# Is it possible to change default fallback message i18n-js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, internationalization

I want to change fallback message on missing translation for [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) ([missing translation "en....."]) Is it possible and how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Vasfed, but now i know easier way to do this.

Just add:

`I18n.t("some.missing.scope", {defaults: [{message: "Some message"}]});`

Instead of [missing translation "bla.bla.bla" ] you will get "Some message".

Answer (score 0):

In library itself it is defined this way:

```js
I18n.missingTranslation = function() {
  var message = '[missing "' + this.currentLocale()
    , count = arguments.length
  ;

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    message += "." + arguments[i];
  }

  message += '" translation]';

  return message;
};
```

you can replace this with your own implementation by reassigning `I18n.missingTranslation` after library is already evaluated.